# Stack trace not shown on console after adding @ResponseStatus for custom exception handling

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to throw a custom exception and pass only the exception message in the response, but I still need to see the full stack trace in the console. My exception is defined as:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class CartNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public CartNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

And I throw the exceptions like:

```
    final Cart cart = cartsRepository.findByUidAndUsername(cartUid, username);
    if(cartModel == null) {
        throw new CartNotFoundException("No cart found with uid: " + cartUid);
    }
```

The json response that I get is in the format:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-09-23T17:04:59.702+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "No cart found with uid: 84b5305f-e6e2-4d34-a665-20f37b8edfe",
    "path": "/carts/84b5305f-e6e2-4d34-a665-20f37b8edfe"
}
```

But the issue is I'm not able to see the full stack trace in the console, after adding the @ResponseStatus annotation on the custom exception. This is a sample of the exception logging strategy I'm planning to use, I would need the full stack trace to be logged in console logs, and the json response as shown here is sufficient. I have tried adding `server.error.include-stacktrace=always` in properties but this gives me the whole stack trace in the message field of the response.

Is there anyway to get just the message in response and the whole trace logged in console? Any way to achieve it using just annotations/property changes? (trying to avoid/reduce writing extra handlers/advices)

Comment: are you using controller advice for handling that exception?

Comment: Thanks, that would help, I can create a controller advice and in the exception handler I can print the stack trace. But is there any way to achieve the same using a property/single config? Basically Im trying to reduce the code as much as possible. It would help me avoid writing the exceptionhandler, the pojo for the json response etc. Trying to find if there is any feature already available, as the only thing I am missing right now is the logging.

Comment: I am also not sure but please check out Spring AOP. It might help you.